# Conditional not working, returns first case always

Tags: c++, operators

The result prints out 'c' 3 times, anyone know why it always meets the first condition?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


char x(char y)
{
    if (y == 'a' || 'b')
    {
        return 'c';
    }
    else if (y == 'c' || 'd')
    {
        return 'e';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'g';
    }
}


int main()
{
    cout << x('a') << endl;
    cout << x('c') << endl;
    cout << x('p') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'b'` is not 0. Therefore, the condition is always true.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: I <3 that people don't bother making it to the end of Chapter 1 of their C++ book before asking I-haven't-RTFM questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need something of the form

```
if (y == 'a' || y == 'b')
```

This is because in this expression

```
(y == 'a' || 'b')
```

you are evaluating an OR of `y == 'a'` and `'b'`, and since `'b'` evaluates to `true` by virtue of being non-zero, the whole expression evaluates to `true`.

```
(y == 'a' || true)
```

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
if (y == 'a' || 'b')
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ((y == 'a') || ('b'))
```

That's because the `==` operator has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `||` operator.

Since `'b'` is non-zero, it always evaluates as true, and so `(y == 'a' || 'b')` always evaluates as true.

You need to write this:

```
if (y == 'a' || y == 'b')
```

Of course, even if the precedence was the other way around,

```
if (y == ('a' || 'b'))
```

would not have been what you intended either!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the operator precedence (priority) here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

In your case the condition expression is:

```
(y == 'a' || 'b')
```

So the “y == 'a'” part is evaluated first which may be true/false depending on the value of "y". Let's call the value of "y=='a'" as "t". And then the expression is evaluated as " t || 'b'" in this case 'b' is actually the ASCII code value of character 'b' (98) which is surely larger than 0, so the result of the boolean expression is always true.

To dismiss any ambiguity caused by operator precedence, I think it's a good habit to use brackets to explicitly express your priority in the evaluation. In your case, as suggested by earlier post, it should be:

```
if ((y=='a') || (y=='b'))
```